# Use Postman to test Appsync Subscription

Tags: websocket, postman, aws-appsync

I have been able to successfully execute Appsync GraphQL queries and mutations from Postman. However, i'm struggling to connect to subscriptions which are websocket urls.

How can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Postman supports WebSockets testing GraphQL subscriptions is achievable as well. Such a testing requires two steps:

- connection to a server,
- sending a `start` message.

---

Establishing a connection:

1. Create a new WebSocket request.
2. Put your server URL `ws://` or `wss://`.
3. Add custom header parameter `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: graphql-ws`. Other headers may depend on your server configuration.
4. Press the "Connect" button.

[image]

---

When the connection is established we may start a subscription.

1. In the "New message" field put the command.
2. Press the "Send" button.

The `start` message should look like this:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "payload": {
      "operationName": "MySubscription",
      "query": "subscription MySubscription {
          someSubscription {
              __typename
              someField1
              someField2 {
                  __typename
                  someField21
                  someField22
              }
          }
      }",
      "variables": null
  },
  "type": "start"
}
```

`operationName` is just the name of your subscription, I guess it's optional. And `someSubscription` must be a subscription type from your schema.

`query` reminds regular GraphQL syntax with one difference:

- `__typename` keyword precedes every field list.

For example, the query from the payload in regular syntax looks like the following:

```
subscription MySubscription {
  someSubscription {
        someField1
        someField2 {
              someField21
              someField22
        }
  }
}
```

---

Example message with parameters (variables):

```
{
      "id":"1",
      "payload": {
           "operationName": "MySubscription",
           "query": "subscription MySubscription($param1: String!) {
                  someSubscription((param1: $param1)) {
                      __typename
                      someField
                  }
            }",
            "variables": {
                  "param1": "MyValue"
            }
      },
      "type": "start"
}
```

It also reminds regular GraphQL syntax as described above.

`variables` is an object with your parameters.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! Also was wondering how i can provide input parameters(filters) to the webclient ? I can do this from appsync console, but in the payload it doesnt work..

Comment: @user1354825 I've added an example with parameters, please, give it a try

Comment: @user1354825 I also mentioned that `query` must be one lined (i.e. I need to remove all the line breaks in those fields). In other case, Postman sends invalid JSON but the server doesn't respond with an error, it just doesn't respond at all

Comment: @VladimirVlasov I am using Postman 10.6.7 and while trying to call appsync wss endpoint I am getting this error: "The \"header\" query string parameter is missing".
Even though I have added the header attributes, appsync complains about not getting the header query param. My endpoint looks like this right now:
wss://example.appsync-realtime-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql?payload={}  
in Postman window Header has x-api-key, Sec-WebSocket-Protocol and host.

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir's answer is spot on. Adding a few notes for folks still having trouble.

Full document here @ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html

Step 1 - establish connection:
make sure to base64 encode values in "header" and "payload" querystrings

header example:

```js
{
    "host":"example1234567890000.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
    "x-api-key":"da2-12345678901234567890123456"
}
```

payload: You can pass in empty payload

```js
{}
```

Step 2 - register subscription:

Include the authorization in the message. Escape line feeds properly "\n" throws an error but "\\n" works. it throws the following error - misleading.

Don't forget to stringify value in "data" field.

{
"type": "error",
"payload": {
"errors": [
{
"errorType": "UnsupportedOperation",
"message": "unknown not supported through the realtime channel"
}
]
}
}

```js
{
  "id": "2",
  "payload": {
    "data": "{\"query\":\"subscription onCreateMessage { changeNotification{  __typename changeType from } }\",\"variables\":{}}",
      "extensions":{
        "authorization":{
          "host":"example1234567890000.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          "x-api-key":"da2-12345678901234567890123456"
          }
        }
  },
  "type": "start"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman supports Graphql queries as well as subscriptions recently. If your Graphql server has introspection turned on, postman will recognize all possible routes/schemas (including subscriptions - websocket ones).
If introspection isn't turned on, you'll still be able to send a subscription message as well. The difference with the approved answer will be that you don't need to set headers, etc. The setup will be much easier.
You would need to pass something like this:

```
subscription OnStatusChange {
onStatusChange(filter: "test") {
    Id
  }
}
```

P.S: The GraphQL subscription WebSocket route will be as same as your main Graphql address.

You can read more about GraphQL Beta support on Postman:
https://blog.postman.com/announcing-postmans-new-graphql-client/

Answer (score 0):

@Vladimir's answer is excellent. But I just being a little stuck checking how to send a text to create the subscription with the example scheme for the AppSync. I use this body, I don't know if there is the easiest way to do this, but maybe it could be helpful to others.

```json
{
  "id": "4",
  "payload": {
    "data": "{\"query\": \"subscription SubscribeToData {\\n subscribe(name: \\\"channel\\\") {\\n name \\n data \\n }}\",\"variables\":{\"message\": \"my message\"}}",
      "extensions": {
        "authorization": {
          "host": "xxx.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          "x-api-key": "da2-xxx"
         }
      }
  },
  "type": "start"
}
```